# How to predict chaining order for future iterations

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, deep-learning

I am actually looking into some predicting algorithms. My Question is I have set of threads in a process lets say T1, T2 , T3 ... T4.  Initially I will be getting some request basing on which I run these threads in a order say T2-T1-T3-T4 and for other request T3-T1-T2-T4 ... and so on for another N iterations. If I want to predict future M request order of execution. which algorithm can I use and how can I predict??

Comment: It depends on determining a suitable model for the request-generation process.  If the requests are completely uncorrelated (for example), then no amount of learning/prediction will help.

Comment: Thanks Oliver....actually they few of them are correlated. others not.